# How to match characters between quotes while comparing one line to another line?

Tags: python, regex, comparison, matching

I'm comparing one line from one file and another line from another file. Each line from both files has the words: chain "...". The characters between quotes that comes after the word, chain, is variable.

How would I get Python to print, chain, followed by the characters between the quotes, upon matching the characters between the quotes?

IE:

Line from file A:   `chain "1234"`
Line from file B:   `chain "4567"`

... don't print. 1234 != 4567

Line from file A: `chain "abcd"`
Line from file B: `chain "abcd"`

...match! So, print: chain "abcd"

Comment: Is the leading/prefix word always going to be `"chain"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fileA = open('path/to/file/A', 'r')
fileB = open('path/to/file/B', 'r')
line1, line2 = fileA.readline(), fileB.readline()
if line1[7 : -1] == line2[7 : -1] :
    print( line1 )
fileA.close()
fileB.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, Reaper! That's assuming that the lines are identical though?

Comment: @JaneHacker Thus will work for any line in the format `chain "any-symbols-here"` (and with any 6-character sequence before the first ").